# Node.js "Cannot POST /[route]"

Tags: node.js

In `util/index.js` I have these methods:

```
'use strict';

const parser        = require('body-parser');
const express       = require('express');
const app           = express();
const RtmClient     = require('@slack/client').RtmClient;
const RTM_EVENTS    = require('@slack/client').RTM_EVENTS;
const db            = require('../db').db;
const rtm           = new RtmClient(process.env.SLACK_API_TOKEN);

app.use(parser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

rtm.start();

let POST = (url, handler) => {
    app.post(url, (req, res) => {
        handler(req)
            .then(data => {
                res.status(200).send(data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                res.status(500).send('Error: ' + error.message || error);
            });
    });
};

let setStatus = url => {
    POST(url, req => db.users.insert({
        username:   req.body.user_name,
        userid:     req.body.user_id,
        status:     url.toUpperCase()
    }));
};

module.exports = {
    POST,
    setStatus
};
```

And in my `project/index.js`, I call them like this:

```
'use strict';

const port          = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const db            = require('./db').db;
const express       = require('express');
const app           = express();
const u             = require('./util');

u.POST('/logdash', () => db.users.select());
u.setStatus('here');
u.setStatus('out');
u.setStatus('break');
u.setStatus('left');
u.setStatus('sick');
u.setStatus('hungry');

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server is now running on port ' + port);
});
```

But then I get `Cannot POST /[route]`. This is a Slack app, and before transferring those two methods into another file, it was working nicely. I yet don't quite understand Node.js, for this is my first app I ever make. I'm used to programming languages like PHP, but then, by doing the same conventional way for method separation into different files, this error is thrown for me.

I believe the issue is in `POST` method, because it displays a message in the channel when a route is accessed and the database operation is done, but I probably need to do something different when requiring it from another file.

Comment: You have two different `app`s (in the two modules), and you're only starting one of them.

Comment: Starting you mean `app.listen`?

Comment: Okay, I've understood. I exported `app` and used `u.app.listen`. Like this, the `/logdash` command worked, but the others still show the same error.

Comment: The issue was a missing `'/'` before `url` parameter in `setStatus`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @SLaks comment, I could think and figured out.

First, I've exported `app`, required and started it like this:

```
u.app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server is now running on port ' + port);
});
```

The other problems were simply because of a missing `'/'` before the `url` parameter in `setStatus` method:

```
let setStatus = url => {
    POST('/' + url, req => db.users.insert({
        username:   req.body.user_name,
        userid:     req.body.user_id,
        status:     url.toUpperCase()
    }));
};
```